# In Rally SDK2, is there an example of adding data to the ReleaseComboBox or IterationComboBox?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I want to be able to add an option for "--ANY--".

This does not work:

```
Ext.create('Rally.ui.ReleaseComboBox', {
            hideLabel: false,
            fieldLabel: "Release: ",
            width: 275,
            allowBlank: true,
            listeners: {
                beforerender: function( dd, opts ) {
                    var store = dd.getStore();

                    store.add( {
                        Name: '--ANY--'
                    });

           etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this example should work.  Try listening to the store load and then use the loadData method to load the data directly into the store, ensuring that the passed in data is the correct format for the ReleaseComboBox.

Also, set the append parameter to true for loadData().  Otherwise, it will remove the existing records from the store and then add the data.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'rallyreleasecombobox',
        storeConfig: { 
            listeners: {
                load: function(store) {
                    store.loadData([{formattedName: '--ANY--', 
                                    formattedStartDate: 'n/a', 
                                    formattedEndDate: 'n/a',
                                    isSelected: false}], 
                                    true);
                    store.sort('formattedStartDate', 'DESC');

                 }
            }
        }    
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
});
```

Comment: That did it!  I have not quite gotten used to the idea of a configuration inside the configuration -- for the store like this one.  Thanks!